# SQL error in Laravel 6 when joining tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

So i wrote this query in phpmyadmin and it is working correctly

```
SELECT als.name,als.airlineCode, flights.planeNumber, flights.departureAirport, 
dep_air.name,flights.departurelTime, flights.arrivalAirport, 
arr_air.name,flights.arrivalTime FROM `flights`
JOIN airports AS dep_air
ON flights.departureAirport = dep_air.airportCode
JOIN airports as arr_air
ON flights.arrivalAirport = arr_air.airportCode
JOIN airlines as als
ON flights.airlineReference = als.airlineCode
WHERE dep_air.airportCode = 'YYZ' AND arr_air.airportCode = 'YUL' ;
```

[here it is in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty91V.png)

however when i try this in laravel in the controller

```
public function formSubmit(){


       $flights = DB::table('flights')
        ->select('als.name','als.airlineCode','flights.planeNumber','flights.departureAirport','dep_air.name','flights.departurelTime','flights.arrivalAirport','arr_air.name','flights.arrivalTime')
        ->join('airports as dep_air','flights.departureAirport','dep_air.airportCode')
        ->join('airports as arr_air' ,'flights.arrivalAirport','arr_air.airportCode')
        ->join('airlines as als,','flights.airlineReference','als.airlineCode')
        ->where('dep_air.airportCode','=', 'YYZ')
        ->where('arr_air.airportCode','=', 'YUL')
        ->get();
        dd($flights);
        return view('oneWayTrips', compact('flights'));
    }
```

I get the following error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'als.name' in 'field list' (SQL: select
>   `als`.`name`, `als`.`airlineCode`, `flights`.`planeNumber`,
>   `flights`.`departureAirport`, `dep_air`.`name`,
>   `flights`.`departurelTime`, `flights`.`arrivalAirport`,
>   `arr_air`.`name`, `flights`.`arrivalTime` from `flights` inner join
>   `airports` as `dep_air` on `flights`.`departureAirport` =
>   `dep_air`.`airportCode` inner join `airports` as `arr_air` on
>   `flights`.`arrivalAirport` = `arr_air`.`airportCode` inner join
>   `airlines` as `als,` on `flights`.`airlineReference` =
>   `als`.`airlineCode` where `dep_air`.`airportCode` = YYZ and
>   `arr_air`.`airportCode` = YUL)

UPDATE:

The query is almost working after the typo fixes but i've noticed one of the values is missing the `arr_air.name` . the `dep_air.name` is working fine and showing the departure airport name, `arr_air.name` represents the name for the arrival airport

this is the query at the moment

[image: Query Now]

Comment: oops thanks for letting me know everyone, however i got a new error that i updated in the original post.

Comment: updated after fixing typo's is it because I have a field called name in all 3 tables so they are overwriting each other because the als.name should be air canada, the other two should be airport names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check "**airlines**" table have "name" field ....

Comment: i double checked i do have a names field in the airlines table.

Comment: i found it their was an extra comma

Comment: yes you told "names" but you using "name" you have to use "names" instead of "name"

Comment: I updated the issue its almost solved but for some reason one of my value's is not displaying like the rest